# How can I get my Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse to work?

Tags: 10.10, mouse, input-devices

I recently got a Sony Vaio VPCEB series laptop and I tried hooking in my external Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 4000 into the computer (it has a small usb flash drive that hooks into the computer).

I suppose I need some driver? Or perhaps I just need to edit some file? I also thought it might be the USB ports not working, but I tried a different USB device and it worked fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: sounds like it is a bluetooth mouse? does your bluetooth icon show up when you plug in the adapter? (it's not a flash drive btw)

Comment: It isn't bluetooth, i know its not a flash drive. I was just trying to describe it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bought a new mouse... it was 10 dollars :)! Thanks for the help everyone. I decided 10 dollars isn't worth the crazy amounts of trouble I was going through...

Answer (score 0):

Slightly odd answer, [but I found this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1405923):

> I had the USB part plugged into the rear of my computer case. I think it is possible that the metal case was partially blocking the RF signal. I've moved to the front USB port and it may be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're experiencing some variation of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/linux/+bug/636311)?